# How to fix W: GPG error:..... NO_PUBKEY?

Tags: gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY” without terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey-without-terminal)

I get this message when I use Update-Manager:

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9BDB3D89CE49EC21

I have no idea what's wrong and how to fix it. Could someone kindly explain what I need to do to fix whatever is wrong? Is there a way to prevent this from happening in the future?